# Calculating frequency of Earths orbit

Tags: physics

If the Earth takes one year to orbit the sun and the frequency is f = 1/T with T being the period.

Then what would the period be ? I am use to dealing with seconds and minutes but this question involves a year.

Comment: What units do you need the final result in?

Comment: Well I'm calculating frequency which is hz but for the period it should be seconds I presume.

Comment: Right, hz is $s^{-1}$. Do you know how to convert from years to seconds?

Comment: No I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T={1\over f}=1 year=365day*24{h\over day}*60{min\over h}*60{s\over min}=31536000s\approx3.15*10^7s$

Comment: I got f = 3.2 x 10^-8[hz] is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, it is right!;-)